# ipmitool sensor: does not detect backup power supply

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, supermicro, power-supply-unit, ipmitool

Why doesn't ipmitool detect my second power supply?

I have 2 powersupplies plugged into my machine, but calling ipmitool sensor only shows PS1:

```
:~$ sudo ipmitool sensor |grep PS
PS1 Status       | 0x1        | discrete   | 0x0b00| na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
```

Unplugging PS1 and rerunning that command gives:

```
:~$ sudo ipmitool sensor |grep PS
PS1 Status       | 0xb        | discrete   | 0x0b00| na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
```

So I know that ipmitool is detecting the first powersupply status correctly, and that the second powersupply is actually plugged in and working (because the **0xB** implies that PS1 has failed, yet the machine is still running)

I'm seeing this issue on multiple units, these machines are:

- SUPERMICRO X9DRW-7TPF+
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- ipmitool: 1.8.13-1ubuntu0.2

.

Answer (score 1):

Unplug all power cables from power supplies. Insert all power supplies into chassis. Plug the power cables into outlet. Then, IPMI should detect all power supplies.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the power_good sensor line from the second power supply outlet to the IPMI is inoperative or it could be that the power_good signal is not being emitted by the second power supply due to some internal failure.

To get power out of a power supply and run the machine, you just need a working switching power supply.

To have IPMI recognize that fact, you also need for the power supplies IPMI smarts to be working and communicating correctly with the IPMI board.

Things to try:

1. Reseat everything as suggested by user373708.
2. Switch power supplies between the two power supply slots and see if the failure follows the power supplies or stays with the slot.

   - If it follows the power supply, replace the non-reporting power supply.
   - If it stays with the slot, replace the chassis in question.

Answer (score 0):

If its a production server shutting it down may not be the right solution.
In  my case ipmi-sensor does not show the second power supply but it shows there are events logs for the second power supply. Go figure.